# Class Cast Exception JSF

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Currently I am playing with JSF, I have an data-table, values will be loaded when ever search filter has done, Moving forward I have an export button, exports the data to xls format. In this scenario data is exported.

But when there is no search done and the data-table is empty which has only column headers, and by clicking on the export icon. I am getting the following exception, Here is the stack trace and Image attached for reference

```
 Apr 21, 2017 4:37:24 PM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase execute
WARNING: javax.faces.model.ListDataModel cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.model.ListDataModel cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.clearLazyCache(DataTable.java:964)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.Exporter.exportAll(Exporter.java:224)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter.export(ExcelExporter.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:97)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.ppts.setting.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Apr 21, 2017 4:37:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/GEO_DM] threw exception [javax.faces.model.ListDataModel cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.model.ListDataModel cannot be cast to org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.clearLazyCache(DataTable.java:964)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.Exporter.exportAll(Exporter.java:224)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter.export(ExcelExporter.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:97)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.ppts.setting.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is the JSF Code which I have Used

```
 <label>Export</label> <span class="info-box-title"> <h:panelGrid
columns="2" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5">
<h:commandLink>
    <img src="images/excel.png" class="img-responsive" />
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="removetagtbl"
        fileName="LeaverJoinerDataxls" 
        postProcessor="#{leaverJoinerTagReportBean.postProcessXLS}"/>

</h:commandLink>

<h:commandLink style="padding-right: 20px;">
    <img src="images/csv.png" />
    <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="removetagtbl"
        fileName="LeaverJoinerDatacsv" />
</h:commandLink>
```

I have used LazyDataModel to add all the datas into a list

Please guide me, and correct me if anything is wrong.

[image]

Here is the code of preparing list using LazyDataModel

```
public class LeaverJoinerReportLazyModel extends LazyDataModel<LeaverJoinerTagReportDTO> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<LeaverJoinerTagReportDTO> datasource;

    public LeaverJoinerReportLazyModel(List<LeaverJoinerTagReportDTO> datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }

    @Override
    public LeaverJoinerTagReportDTO getRowData(String rowKey) {
        for (LeaverJoinerTagReportDTO leaverJoinerTagReportDTO : datasource) {
            if (leaverJoinerTagReportDTO.getLineId().equals(rowKey))
                return leaverJoinerTagReportDTO;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(LeaverJoinerTagReportDTO leaverJoinerTagReportDTO) {
        return leaverJoinerTagReportDTO.getLineId();
    }

    @Override
    public List<LeaverJoinerTagReportDTO> load(int first, int pageSize,
            String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

        List<LeaverJoinerTagReportDTO> dataList = new ArrayList<LeaverJoinerTagReportDTO>();

        // filter
        for (LeaverJoinerTagReportDTO leaverJoinerTagReportDTO : datasource) {
            boolean match = true;

            if (filters != null) {
                for (Iterator<String> iterator = filters.keySet().iterator();iterator.hasNext();) {
                    try {
                        String sFilterProperty = iterator.next();
                        Object sFilterValue = filters.get(sFilterProperty);
                        String sFieldValue = String.valueOf(leaverJoinerTagReportDTO.getClass().getField(sFilterProperty).get(leaverJoinerTagReportDTO));
                        if (sFilterValue == null    || sFieldValue.startsWith(sFilterValue.toString())) {
                            match = true;
                        } else {
                            match = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        match = false;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                //Do Nothing
            }

            if (match) {
                dataList.add(leaverJoinerTagReportDTO);
            }
        }

        // rowCount
        int dataSize = dataList.size();
        this.setRowCount(dataSize);

        // paginate
        if (dataSize > pageSize) {
            try {
                return dataList.subList(first, first + pageSize);
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                return dataList.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));
            }
        } else {
            return dataList;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the exception is pretty clear, isn't it? You are using `javax.faces.model.ListDataModel` somewhere, and Primefaces tries to cast this to `org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel` inside the `clearLazyCache`-Method.

`LazyDataModel` can be casted to `DataModel` (upcast, always possible), therefore you might be able to implicit cast it back (downcast), if the actual Type during runtime was `LazyDataModel` before.

```
java.lang.Object
  javax.faces.model.DataModel<T>
    org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel<T>
```

https://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.0/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html

But `ListDataModel` is part of another tree-leaf, therefore this cast fails.

```
java.lang.Object
  javax.faces.model.DataModel<E>
    javax.faces.model.ListDataModel<E>
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/ListDataModel.html

Maybe you should add your bean-code, not only the markup of the page.

Comment: Hi, but I have not used ListDataModel anywhere in my project, please refer the code I have attached, moving forward in bean I am just getting object of the class which is above and using that object, Iteration is done in JSF page in datatable using the getters of respective bean

Comment: Yup, i am using PF 5.1

Comment: Then it's a known bug -> Upgrade PF. - see the link :) (Fixed in 5.2)

Comment: Yup Thank you soo much, I am clear now and will move forward with upgrading

Answer (score 2):

If you use lazy="true" on your datatable you must use LazyDataModel as value in datatable. Just put it false if you want to use a normal Java List.